# Daphne issue when upgrading django from 1.11 to 2.0

Tags: python, django, daphne

When upgraded from django 1.11 to 2.0 this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.local/share/virtualenvs/django2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/daphne/http_protocol.py", line 179, in process
    "server": self.server_addr,
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Django version 2.0.10, channels=2.1.6, daphne=2.2.4. This happens as soon as a GET request is sent to localhost:8000. 
Tried with manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000.

Offending line:

```
self.application_queue = self.server.create_application(self, {
                "type": "http",
                # TODO: Correctly say if it's 1.1 or 1.0
                "http_version": self.clientproto.split(b"/")[-1].decode("ascii"),
                "method": self.method.decode("ascii"),
                "path": unquote(self.path.decode("ascii")),
                "root_path": self.root_path,
                "scheme": "https" if self.isSecure() else "http",
                "query_string": self.query_string,
                "headers": self.clean_headers,
                "client": self.client_addr,
                "server": self.server_addr,  # <<<<<<<<< OFFENDING LINE
            })
```